# Sub imageview, Label and Button is not showing on android simulator for Titanium

Tags: android, imageview, label, titanium

I am developing multi platform app by using Titanium SDK.
Then this code is working well on iOS but not working on android.
I write the .tss and .xml code here.

-----------------.tss file-------------------------

```
 ".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
}

"#select_language_pannel": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: '84%',
    height: '45%',  
    image: '/images/select_language_pannel.png'
}

"#language_label":{
    top: '20%',
    color : '#008c99',
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    text: L('select_language'),
    font: {fontSize: '18dp', fontWeight:"bold"}
}

"#arabic_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '40%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',    
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#arabic_text": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    color: '#008c99',
    height: '100%',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}

"#english_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '60%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#english_text": {
    color: '#008c99',
    height: '100%',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
"#select_language_pannel": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    width: '84%',
    height: '45%',  
    image: '/images/select_language_pannel.png'
}

"#language_label":{
    top: '20%',
    color : '#008c99',
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    text: L('select_language'),
    font: {fontSize: '18dp', fontWeight:"bold"}
}

"#arabic_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '40%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',    
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#arabic_text": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    color: '#008c99',
    height: '100%',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}

"#english_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '60%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#english_text": {
    color: '#008c99',
    height: '100%',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
```

-----------------.xml file-----------------

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" id = "win">
        <ImageView image="/images/selectlanguage_bg.png">
            <ImageView id="select_language_pannel">
                <Label id = "language_label"></Label>
                <Button id = "arabic_button" onClick="onClickArabic" onFocus="onFocusArabic" >
                    <Label id = "arabic_text" zIndex="100">عـربـي</Label>
                </Button>
                <Button id = "english_button" onClick="onClickEnglish"  onFocus="onFocusEnglish">
                    <Label id = "english_text" zIndex="100">ENGLISH</Label>
                </Button>
            </ImageView>
        </ImageView>        
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting elements which should not be nested. As explained on your other question, a `button` cannot have a `label` nested.

Of course, the same goes for `ImageViews` which should not have nested elements.

Instead, you should position elements on top of each other using `tss`.

Your XML should look something like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" id = "win">
        <ImageView image="/images/selectlanguage_bg.png" />
        <ImageView id="select_language_pannel" />
        <Label id = "language_label"></Label>
        <Button id = "arabic_button" onClick="onClickArabic" onFocus="onFocusArabic" ></Button>
        <Button id = "english_button" onClick="onClickEnglish"  onFocus="onFocusEnglish"></Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

When this XML is in place, position elements over each other using tss and, where needed, zIndex.

Comment: Rene is right. On iOS is ok to put a Label or Activity Indicator inside a button.
On Android this doesn't work. I suggest you to change the ImageView for a simple View and instead of "image" make use of "backgroundImage"